# Making a huge block of text not overflow outside of the screen and instead overflow on the bottom of the screen

Tags: html, css

Right now I am trying to make just a stupid sub domain for my game domain. It's just showing the first hundreds of thousands of digits of pie. obviously with so many digits it goes off the page. Instead of the digits going off of the page on the y axis I want it going down the page on the x axis. I'm not entirely sure how to do this as I am no coding master mind.

I have tried to do this by adding a max width to the body, and I have tried setting a width for the p element in style, but none of that worked.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>π</title>
  <style>
      body {
        width: 1000px;
        overflow-y: auto;
      }

      h1 {
        margin: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
      }

      p {
        color: grey;
        margin: auto;
      }

  </style>
</head>


<body max-width='1000'>
    <h1>Ever wondered what the first thousands of digits of pi are 
but you never could... Well ugbrain has solved that problem...</h1>

    <p>DIGITS OF PIE GO HERE</p>
```

I expect instead of the results to be scrolling down on the x axis and not all on one line in the y axis.

Comment: So, you are calling your own project stupid?

Comment: Note that the attribute `max-width='1000'` on the body does not do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your body width to a fluid size to avoid having a horizontal scroll on `body` element. Or use media queries to make sure your body width is not larger then viewport width.

Next set your pi element to `word-break: break-all;` to get the digits over multiple lines. For example:

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  margin: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
}

p {
  color: grey;
  max-width: 100%;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Ever wondered what the first thousands of digits of pi are but you never could... Well ugbrain has solved that problem...</h1>

  <p>3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679821480865132823066470938446095505822317253594081284811174502841027019385211055596446229489549303819644288109756659334461284756482337867831652712019091456485669234603486104543266482133936072602491412737245870066063155881748815209209628292540917153643678925903600113305305488204665213841469519415116094330572703657595919530921861173819326117931051185480744623799627495673518857527248912279381830119491298336733624406566430860213949463952247371907021798609437027705392171762931767523846748184676694051320005681271452635608277857713427577896091736371787214684409012249534301465495853710507922796892589235420199561121290219608640344181598136297747713099605187072113499999983729780499510597317328160963185950244594553469083026425223082533446850352619311881710100031378387528865875332083814206171776691473035982534904287554687311595628638823537875937519577818577805321712268066130019278766111959092164201989</p>

</body>
```

Comment: Fluid width will still result in horizontal scroll.

Comment: Test your snippet with actual Pi value and you'll see.

Comment: Ok. That would be default browser `margin` for body. Horizontal scroll fixed.

Comment: Ok. A few more adjustments and you copied my answer completly.

Comment: Huh @Brainfeeder? Not quite, you still have a horizontal scrollbar for body ;)

Comment: Don’t know what browser you use, but I never get a horizontal scrollbar.

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>π</title>
        <style>
            body, html {
                width: 100%;
                height:100%;
            }
            h1 {
                margin: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
            }
            .pi {
                color: grey;
                max-width:100%;
                word-break:break-all;
            }

        </style>
    </head>


    <body>
        <h1>Ever wondered what the first thousands of digits of pi are 
        but you never could... Well ugbrain has solved that problem...</h1>

        <p class="pi">DIGITS OF PIE GO HERE</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Set body margin to 0 to remove last horizontal scrollbar

Answer (score -1):

Use css for that:

```
p {
  color: grey;
  margin: auto;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

This will break your string and put it into the next line.

Comment: It will still depend on body width. If body width is 1000px and viewport is 640px, you will still have horizontal scrolling

Comment: I don't understand why the OP sets the `body` to 1000px... I think it was his attempt to try and solve his problem. `body` should adjust to viewport in most cases.